# scrollTop not working in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, scrolltop

I have a link that i want to click and i'd like it to scroll. This works on firefox but doesn't work on chrome.

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="login-link">
        <a href="#login">Login</a><!-- Link that i intend to click -->
    </li>
</ul>


<div>
    <a id="login"></a><!-- Link that i want to scroll to -->
<div>
```

Here is my javascript

```
$('#nav').on('click', '.login-link a', function(e) {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top }, 1000,      "easeOutExpo");
    return false;

});
```

I've researched but to no avail. Is this a bug in Chrome or is there some issue with my code. Do i need to change anything in my CSS for it to work.

Thank you.

Comment: I've tried adding e.preventDefault() inside the on() method function but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Seems to work for me on [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4q2WP/).

Comment: I think there must be an issue with my CSS.

Comment: `$(this).attr('href')` doesn’t always return what you think it does. Especially in IE the browser might add a full URL instead of just the hash. Hence it’s recommendable to use `this.hash` instead. — If this solves your problem, I can’t say, considering the comments above.